# dynamic sql result not shown in DevExpress DataGrid

Tags: sql, select, datagrid, count, xtragrid

I am trying the following sql statement on a simple windows form textbox:

select count(*) from job_orders;

then I am running the code using the following:

when I use the dtandared DataGrid from Microsoft Visual studio I get the correct result (total_count) in the row

but when I use the same with DevExpress xtraGrid I just get blank row although other sql statements are working fine in xtraGrid such as:

Select * from job_orders;

here is the code:

```
sql_connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=MyDB;Uid=root;Pwd=MyPwd;Connect Timeout=360;");
sql_connection.Open();
sql_command = new MySqlCommand(txtQuery.Text, sql_connection);
sql_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sql_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql_command);
sql_adapter.Fill(data_table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.ResetBindings();
dataGridView1.DataSource = data_table;
```

http://www.xoompage.com - http://www.jassimrahma.com

Comment: where is data biding method? You have to call this method dataGridView1.DataBind() after DataSource is set.

Comment: This is WinForm. Databind is need in WebForm only. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6698cad-15f7-41e7-82c3-cc71c17f30e2/datagridview-no-databind

Comment: Ok I see. Why don't you debug where is data inside data_table? MessageBox.Show(data_table.Tables[0].Rows.Count) ?

Comment: but as mentioned, I am getting the correct result from the data table when I bind the standard VS data grid

Comment: Hi, problem is solved. Thank you. It was my mistake :(- Thank you so much